# Can't see raspberry in router hostname list

Tags: pi-2

Today I've changed my Internet connection provider, so I've got a new modem. I tried to execute the port forwarding but in the device list I can't see my raspberry.

In the past I've configured the raspberry pi hostname as: webserver. I also have samba installed on the raspberry.

Actually if in Windows 10 command prompt I do: ping webserver, I'll get the four packages sended and correctly reiceved.
Why in my modem I can't see my raspberry?

Comment: You can't see your RPi on a modem because it's a modem. You need a router to manage connection between devices and build a local network.

Comment: If you're mistaken and have a modem/router combo, you'll need to check support for your device. There isn't a lot we can do to help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a DNS issue as your new modem can't translate the 'webserver' name to an IP address.

Was your old modem also your DNS server? If so, you may just need to add a DNS entry for your webserver. If not, where is your DNS server, and does your new modem know where to look for DNS?

You could also just use port forwarding to the IP address of the PI, rather than the host name.

Comment: I've assigned already the port to the Ip of my raspberry but no luck, guess I need to call my provider for further explaination